# Aggregation along with extra values

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to get the `aggregate` along with its `id`.
I have a model called `Index`.

```
class Index(Model):
    correlation = DecimalField()
    company = CharField()


------------------------------
| id | correlation | company |
------------------------------
| 1  | 0.99        | A       |
| 2  | 0.43        | A       |
| 3  | 0.67        | B       |
| 4  | 0.94        | B       |
| 5  | 0.23        | C       |
------------------------------
```

I need my query to return

```
[
 {
  'id': 1,
  'correlation': 0.99,
  'company': 'A'
 },
 {
  'id': 4,
  'correlation': 0.94,
  'company': 'B'
 },
 {
  'id': 5,
  'correlation': 0.23,
  'company': 'C'
 }
]
```

Explanation: Since Company `A` has a Maximum correlation of `0.99` at id `1` it is returned.
So Basically I need to retrieve `id` of max correlation for all the companies.

I tried

`Index.objects.values('company').annotate(correlation_max = Max('correlation'))`. 
`Index.objects.values('company', 'id').annotate(correlation_max = Max('correlation'))`.

None of them are working. I couldn't able to get the `id`.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181854/aggregation-and-extra-values-with-django). but I need `id` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all items with the same `company`, order them by descending `correlation` and just pick the first one (with the highest correlation):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

company_correlations = Index.objects.filter(company=OuterRef('company')).order_by('-correlation')
max_correlations = Index.objects.filter(id=Subquery(company_correlations.values('id')[:1])).values('id', 'correlation', 'company')
```

Not very elegant, I'm sure there must be a more elegant way, but I've tested this and it works.

Comment: Here's a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55949013/django-oldest-entry-for-distinct-fields#answer-55949297), but it uses a subquery as well. When you would use nested queries in raw SQL, you're stuck with subqueries in Django's ORM.